# Move down overflow contents in horizontal stackpanel

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a list box in expander:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySource">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding MyContent}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I wrap the radio button with horizontal orientation stackpanel. I want the overflow radio buttons move down like right image shown below (no horizontal scrollbar). Now, mine is like the left one.

[Stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" http://www.empirepic.com/images/i8f5sevyzqch10uodso.jpg](http://www.empirepic.com/images/i8f5sevyzqch10uodso.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a WrapPanel, not a StackPanel. In WPF it's built into the main assemblies but in Silverlight you'll need to get the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding MyContent}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <t:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty should be ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility. The rest is perfect! Thanks, Josh!

Comment: That's what I get for being lazy and copying and pasting the name. :) Thanks for the heads up.